# How do I install the latest Python version in Ubuntu?

Tags: python3

How to update to the latest Python version in Ubuntu? I tried `sudo apt-get install python3` but it says that the current (3.3.1) is already the latest.

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you have? 12.04?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Any reason why you need 3.3.2 instead of 3.3.1?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this PPA (notice, I haven't tested it, but it *looks* fine): https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes

To do this, open a terminal, and run this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes # Adds the PPA
sudo apt-get update # Updates the lists
```

And then run the system updates (I would recommend this over `sudo apt-get install python3` because other packages may need to be updated for it to work fine):

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # dist-upgrade might be needed if python3
                          # needs to install or remove packages
                          # for it to work
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 13.04 comes with pre-loaded python3 (3.3.2). So you may already have python3 (3.3.2) installed. try `python3` in terminal instead of just `python`

Comment: It's 3.3.1 (with some backports from 3.3.2), but yeah, 3.3.x is already present.