# python 3.3.2 installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, python

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and already have python 2.7 installed. I need python 3.3.2 to be installed for some course. So i am trying to do that. I found this ubuntu link

[How do I install the latest Python version in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310441/install-python-3-3-2-on-ubuntu)

I tried to do the same. It was succesful but it's not running python 3.3.2 but running python 3.2.3. How should i install python 3.3.2?

Comment: I tried to do sudo apt-get install python3.3. I get the following error.The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libh323plus-dev : Depends: libpt2.4.5-dev but it is not going to be installed
 Conflicts: libopenh323-dev but 1.18.0.dfsg-10build2 is to be installed
 libopenh323-1.18.0 : Conflicts: libopenh323-1.18.0-develop but 1.18.0.dfsg-10build2 is to be installed
 libopenh323-1.18.0-develop : Conflicts: libopenh323-1.18.0 but 1.18.0.dfsg-10build2 is to be installed
Conflicts: libopenh323-1.18.0-ptrace
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd try

```
pip install python3.3.2 --user
```

or

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2
tar xf Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2
cd Python-3.3.2
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make && sudo make altinstall
```

In both cases You should then try to start it with

```
$ python3.3
```