# confused about installing python 3.3.4 on ubuntu 12.04lts

Tags: python

I know it's a basic question, but a lot of the information out there is outdated on stack overflow. When I used the suggest apt-get command, I could only installed python3.2.3. And when I finally installed python 3.3.4 manually, I am missing the zlib module. This entirely is really frustrating me, precisely because it's seem so  basic.

I would really appreciated if someone could point me out an up to date guide or tell me how to install the lastest python 3.3.4 in the correct directory with all the right module.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is PPA for Trusty. You can use it on Saucy, but I don't know will it work on Precise or not.
You can enable it by these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/python3
sudo sed -i 's/precise/trusty/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-python3-precise.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

The very simple way is to install with Ubuntu Software Center. It will automatically setup everything for you.

Open `Ubuntu Software Center` > Type `python` on search bar > Scroll down.. you will find `python(v3.3)` > Click <kbd>More Info</kbd> > Click <kbd>Install</kbd>

[image]

Now Open Terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

Type `python3` > Press **Enter** > You should see the `version 3.3.2+` there. Happy coding. :)

Comment: I am running ubuntu 12.04 lts, python3.3 doesn't show up for me, only python 3.2. I guess I am just stuck with that

Comment: Seems like your problem -- http://askubuntu.com/a/316592/148826