# Is it possible to install newest version of Python via apt-get?

Tags: installation, package-management, python

I started a programming course which requires Python 3.3.2. However, in my Ubuntu I can install only version 3.3.1. Is it possible to modify the repositories so that I can install the newest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I started a programming course which requires Python 3.3.2

The [changelog for 3.3.2](http://docs.python.org/release/3.3.2/whatsnew/changelog.html) shows us that there's no serious work in 3.3.2 over 3.3.1. It's a load of minor bugfixes which won't make any difference for somebody on a programming course.

There are big differences between 2.x and 3.x so you will need to install `python3.3` and use the `python3` binary (you'll have to be conscious about that when you're running examples), but don't worry about being a minor release behind, you're not missing out on anything relevant and it won't affect your coding.

I would go further and say that if you end up on a repository that gets you a later version, it might not bring in security patches  and you may be vulnerable for longer than you would be with the standard repository.

That said, if you really want to upgrade, [you should be able to](https://askubuntu.com/a/310443/449) but that comes with the caveat:

> I do not guarantee any kind of updates. In particular, I shed all responsibility for security issues in these packages.