# Python 3.5 has just been released, can I get it as a package for Ubuntu 15.4?

Tags: apt, python

I want the very latest version of Python, but I don't want to bypass the apt package manager: I don't want to do an old-school source install because that can make it harder to uninstall when the official packages come out.

Python3.5 is not currently featured in any of Canonical's package repositories, which means I cannot just "apt-get install python3.5".

Is there a way to get Python3.5 installed on my PC in the meantime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Python 3.3.2 on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/310441/install-python-3-3-2-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Not a duplicate: Python 3.3.x comes with Ubuntu, python 3.5 is brand new and not yet part of an official package.

Comment: It is a duplicate. The answer is the same. That question was simply asked at a time when 3.3.2 was the new version. Use the PPA. Python 3.5 was being built in it when I voted this as a duplicate.

Comment: There is now - Oct. 6th - a PPA with Python3.5 available. See my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/install-python-3-5-on-vivid-using-apt-get)

Comment: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/README

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before Ubuntu adds `python 3.5` to the official repositories you have two options to install it now :

- Check if someone has come with a PPA containing `python 3.5` so that you can install/remove it using `apt-get` or other package manager
- Install from source

As fas as i can see there is no such PPA available till date so your only option is to install from source file.

---

You have said :

> I don't want to do an old-school source install because that can make
>   it harder to uninstall when the official packages come out.

Perhaps you have not heard of [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) yet, it creates a package out of the files that are going to be saved on different places in your computer at the last step of compiling a package from source (`sudo make install`). So you just need to replace `sudo make install` with `sudo checkinstall` and then you can remove the package you named using any package manager in the usual manner.

Check `man checkinstall` to get more idea.

---

**Update:**

A PPA is now available. Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/710865/216503).

Comment: It's not necessary for python, because it's already have a target in MakeFile called `altinstall`. it's working well for many years in all distros.

Answer (score 15):

There is a another answer to a similar question here:
[How do I install newer Python versions using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/install-python-3-5-on-vivid-using-apt-get)

Basically, it says that (until official repositories have the new python version) ***here*** is a source to use with the package manager, for us who prefer to use this simpler method, as that's what package managers are there for:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

Kudos to Felix Krull, who runs this PPA!

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 15.04. I was able to get Python 3.5.1 installed using this method. However, I had to manually do:  sudo rm  /usr/bin/python3, then sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3