# How to install Python 3.4.5 from apt?

Tags: apt, python, python3

I have Python 3.5 installed.I previously installed Python 3.4 from source and managed to uninstall it somehow. Now if I try to install Python 3.4 through `apt-get install python3.4` , it returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpython3.4-minimal' for regex 'python3.4'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Directly executing `python3.4 --version` does't work as well. What should I do?

Comment: Python 3.4 is not in the official repositories for Ubuntu 16.04. Do you really need Python 3.4?

Comment: Yes I need Python 3.4 to run kivy. Also, does this mean that python 3.4 is already installed somewhere on my computer? If I can't use it then at least I want to get completely rid of it.

Comment: `kivy` can run on Python 3.5 as far as I can tell.

Comment: I have another machine running windows, and while most of the time I am on my linux machine, I sometimes also need to get on my windows machine. Since Python 3.5 is not supported by kivy on Windows, I want to use 3.4 on my linux machine as well since I work on the same project from both machines and working with 3.4 on one and with 3.5 on the other can cause issues (or can it?).

Comment: Ah okay, it makes more sense now. I will write up something now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you can see from http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3.4&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all, there is no package for `python3.4` for Ubuntu 16.04. You can compile and install Python 3.4 from source, but if you are not familiar with doing it or prefer to install packages using the APT package manager, I would recommend installing it from a well-known PPA that provides a variety of versions of Python for many Ubuntu versions.

1. Add the `deadsnakes` PPA (read more about it at https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
   ```
2. Install `python3.4`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install python3.4
   ```

According to https://askubuntu.com/a/682875/15003,`/usr/bin/python3` should still be symlinked to `/usr/bin/python3.5`. Therefore, if you want to call Python 3.4, you would need to type the full path to it, which is `/usr/bin/python3.4`. To avoid accidentally breaking other programs, I **strongly** recommend you to **not** change the symlink that `/usr/bin/python3` points to and instead just use `/usr/bin/python3.4` whenever you need to call Python 3.4.

Alternatively, a popular method to manage multiple versions of Python, which I personally recommend, is to use `virtualenv`. You can read more about it at https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/; further elaboration of it in this post seems too far off the intent of the question.

Comment: Unfortunately the repository is not supported anymore.

Comment: @tomasz74 Huh, I only just realized that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The repo moved to https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. So it's now `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`. Only works for Ubuntu up to 16.04

Comment: @Suor Thanks for the information; I have updated my post.