# I removed python2 and python3; Terminal won't launch now!

Tags: command-line, python3, python-2.7

I'm still getting around Ubuntu and the Terminal. I know a bit of Python, so I figured I could install the latest stable release of Python. When I launched python on the Terminal, it started Python 2.7.3, So I figured that Python 3.5.2 wasn't installed.

Anyway, I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-newer-python-versions-using-apt-get/682875) Ask Ubuntu thread to install it, but didn't take care to read the following:

> DON'T change the symlink! There are apparently many system functions
>   that don't work properly with python3.5.
>
> I tried this and afterwards couldn't open a terminal, software
>   updater,...

And well, now I can't open the terminal. I'm able to use X-Term, but I really want to fix this.

I typed the following in the Terminal:

```
sudo rm python2
sudo rm python3
```

and then closed the Terminal.

Comment: Can you open `xterm`? or get to a Virtual Terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F2 etc.)? is so, you should simply be able to relink the appropriate executables e.g. `sudo ln -s python2.7 /usr/bin/python2`

Comment: Yes, I'm able to open xterm, but I still can't use the Terminal (as in, the other application)

Comment: Did you try recreating the symbolic link, as suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: I tried `sudo ln -s python2.7 /usr/bin/python2`. It went through, but the Xterm outputs "failed to create symbolic link 'usr/bin/python2': File exists"

Comment: I'm not sure how I should use the Virtual Terminal, I'm searching about that one. I might go dark since I'm using college wi-fi (home internet is down). Sorry!

Comment: You should be able to execute the command from `xterm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your Xterm terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal
```

then reinstall it with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```