# How to use pip after python 3 build

Tags: python, pip

I have successfully built and installed python 3.5.2 from source code. At the end of the installation it says pip is collected and installed.

```
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting setuptools
Collecting pip
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1 setuptools-20.10.1
```

However after I refresh the bash environment I still get the error.

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

How do I use the pip installed from the build?

Comment: Any reason why you installed Python 3.5.2 from source?

Comment: @edwinksl apt-get gives me python 3.4, I want to have python 3.5. Or is there another way I am not aware of?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-newer-python-versions-using-apt-get.