# Running Pip3 ImportError: cannot import name 'main'

Tags: python3, pip

I want to install Scipy (already have Numpy installed). I have Python 3.5.1-3 installed with OS and IDLE3 (3.5.2). When I hit in terminal

```
sudo pip3 install scipy
```

It prints out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

I've already tried to reinstall pip3 and restart OS, but it didn't change.
Has pip3 been working weirdly with someone else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

numpy and scipy are in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install numpy and scipy for Python 3.x open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update    
sudo apt install python3-numpy python3-scipy
```

For Python 2.x it's:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends python2.7-minimal python2.7 # this line is only necessary for Ubuntu 17.10 and later 
sudo apt install python-numpy # 20.04 and earlier
sudo apt install python-scipy # 18.04 and earlier
```

Comment: python3-scipy worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: As another answer states, this answer is not related to the underlying issue, which has to do with pip.

Comment: It's bad method...

Comment: Chaining the user to pip instead using the default repositories is not always automatically the best solution. There is a security advantage to installing software from the default Ubuntu repositories. Anyone can upload software to PyPI where pip often gets its packages from, and the packages in PyPI are not reviewed as strictly as the packages in the default Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 32):

**Use `python -m pip install` instead of `pip install`**

Example:

```
python -m pip install --user somepackage
python3 -m pip install --user somepackage
```

I started getting this problem after a `pip` upgrade:

```
pip install --upgrade --user pip
```

The `pip` (resp. `pip3`) executable is provided by your distro (`python-pip` package on Ubuntu 16.04).

Therefore, it is not kept up-to date with the `pip` package itself as you upgrade pip, and may break.

If you just use `python -m pip` directly, e.g. as in:

```
python -m pip install --user somepackage
python3 -m pip install --user somepackage
```

it goes through your Python path and finds the latest version of pip, and executes that file.

It relies on the fact that that file is executable, but that is a very standard type of interface, and therefore less likely to break than the hackier Debian script.

Then I recommend adding the following functions to your `.bashrc`:

```
pip() ( python -m pip "$@" )
pip3() ( python3 -m pip "$@" )
```

The Ubuntu 18.04 `/usr/bin/pip3` file does:

```
from pip import main
```

and presumably `main` was removed from `pip` at some point which is what broke things.

The breaking pip commit appears to be: [95bcf8c5f6394298035a7332c441868f3b0169f4 "Move all internal APIs to pip._internal"](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/95bcf8c5f6394298035a7332c441868f3b0169f4) which went into pip 18.0.

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04 after an update from `pip3` 9.0.1 to 18.0.

**pyenv**

Ultimately however, for serious Python development I would just recommend that you install your own local Python with pyenv + virtualenv, which would also get around this Ubuntu bug: [How do I install a different Python version using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get/1195153#1195153)

Comment: So this works, but I can't be the only one who's shaking my head here. Where is the breakdown? Why does the default pip upgrade fail to set the new pip up in a way that has it continue to work?

Comment: @StevenLu my understanding is that `/usr/bin/pip` is provided by an Ubuntu Python package, and `pip` does not overwrite it. But the `pip update` is managed by `pip` itself, and avoids touching Ubuntu files.

Comment: Hi ho same experience here.  Pip3 would NOT work not matter what I did.  This solution works, but how come??  The python pip script is prepared by `Debian` --The comment says:  `Run the main entry point, similarly to how setuptools does it, but because we didn't install the actual entry point from setup.py, don't use the pkg_resources API.`  Perhaps there is a way to install Python properly in a python-way.

Comment: @will I'm not sure about that documentation comment, but I'm sure what the code of `/usr/bin/pip` does :-)

Comment: Just to be clear, the lines you're recommending be added to .bashrc are functions, not aliases. An alias would be like `alias pip3='python3 -m pip'` which would also work. Using a function is fine, but has a few key differences. For example, if you `exit` in a function sourced by your shell, your shell session will be terminated.

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman thanks, I understand, updated to be more correct

Answer (score 20):

The bug is found in pip 10.0.0.

In linux you need to modify file: /usr/bin/pip from:

```
from pip import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

to this:

```
from pip import __main__
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(__main__._main())
```

Comment: This style of workaround does [not seem recommended](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1141#issuecomment-381421570) by the `pip` team.

Comment: You saved my day!!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, but uninstall and reinstall with apt and pip didn't work for me.

I saw another solution that presents a easy way to recover pip3 path:

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall
```

Comment: This downgraded my version of pip3 from 19.0.3 to 8.1.1, but it did fix the symptom.

Answer (score 6):

While karel may have solved your "install numpy and scipy" problem, what's wrong with pip on your system hasn't been addressed, so you'll probably have more problems with pip going forward.

Looking [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240), it seems to be a pretty common recent issue with pip 10 on Ubuntu systems. You may find some work arounds on that thread that work for you, but hopefully an update will fix it soon.

Comment: Thank you for actually fixing the problem and not giving a work-around that only solves the problem partially and for only a single person...

Answer (score 3):

Installing pip from both apt and pip itself can cause this.

In my case, I used Ubuntu's pip package to install pipenv which then installed a newer copy of pip. Now because my shell runs Ubuntu's pip 9 script (to verify run `which pip3`) and my Python interpreter then imports the pip 10 module, the pip3 command fails. So I want to uninstall one of the two.

It's fair to assume you have the newer pip for a reason. In that case you want to uninstall the older pip like so:

`sudo apt remove python3-pip`

If you know for sure that you're fine with the older pip and prefer the system package you'll want to uninstall the newer one:

`~/.local/bin/pip3 uninstall pip`

or failing that

`sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 uninstall pip`

Answer (score 1):

My issue ended up being a mismatch between python3.6 and 3.7.  The python3.6 installation put a link in `/usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.6` even though the system had upgraded to python3.7.

```
sudo apt purge python-pip
sudo apt purge python3-pip
sudo apt install python3.7 --reinstall
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm python3
sudo ln -s python3.7 python3
python3 --version
pip3 --version
```

Answer (score 1):

type

```
hash -d pip3
```

This should remove this error

Comment: Could you give more explanation on your answer: what is 'hash' and why would it remove the error?

Answer (score 1):

Force reinstalling pip works just fine for most of the users as shown on [this](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1141#issuecomment-394574204) github page:

```
python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip
```

Comment: thank you. All previous answers failed miserably, whereas yours worked

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
pip install --upgrade --user pip
```

By `install --upgrade`, I mean whatever you're trying to install.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem after a fresh mint install. The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt install python3-distutils
```

Solution found [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5356):