# How can I install Python 3.5 for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, python3, tox

For some tox tests, I need a Python 3.5 interpreter. How can I install it on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/682869/350004