# Install Python 2.7.6 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi i am trying to install python2.7.6 on my 16.04 cloud image. Its giving the following `on - apt install python=2.7.6`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python
```

Comment: Is there any reason to not use the [default version 2.7.11](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a different Python version using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get)

Answer (score 6):

Use the following command instead:

```bash
sudo apt-get install python-minimal
```

This will give you the most recommended python version 2.7.12. But if you must install 2.7.6 then do the following:

```
wget  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz
tar xf Python-2.7.6.tgz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You can switch between different versions using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Comment: I can't see how this will help - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-minimal  (2.7.12)