# Changing back the default python version to 3.7 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: python3, 19.04

I installed python3.5.2 on my Ubuntu 19.04 for some reason, and now I want to make the python3.7 the default for `python3` command on terminal and even remove the 3.5.2 version from my system.
The installation process of 3.5.2 was [manual](https://askubuntu.com/a/890959/884330), and there is not a `python3.5.2` in `/usr/bin` directory:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/python*

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar  4 19:18 /usr/bin/python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar  4 19:18 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3691008 Apr  6 06:12 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Apr  6 06:12 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar  4 19:18 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 Jun 11 10:25 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4877888 Apr  3 10:09 /usr/bin/python3.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Apr  3 10:09 /usr/bin/python3.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4877888 Apr  3 10:09 /usr/bin/python3.7m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Apr  3 10:09 /usr/bin/python3.7m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar 26 14:55 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Mar 26 14:55 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.7m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Mar 26 14:55 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.7m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Mar  4 19:18 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2-config


$ python3.7 -V
Python 3.7.3

$ python3.5 -V
Python 3.5.2

$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

Some other functionalities in the system are broken too. For example, when I use `jupyter notebook` it uses python3.5.2 as its kernel and it doesn't recognize the libraries I've installed for the 3.7 version.
So how can I restore the python version to the Ubuntu 19.04 default?

Comment: @tatsu `no matches found: python*`

Comment: @tatsu It exploded my ubuntu and now I can't login to OS. pufff

Comment: @tatsu I solved it by mounting the partitions using a live cd. Now, the old and main problem.

Comment: I'm out of ideas uninstalling and reinstaling should have done it

Comment: I've found it impossible to have 3.6 and 3.7 side by side. This is a major problem for someone who codes and needs the 3.7 features.