# How do I install a specific patch number version of Python?

Tags: apt, software-installation, python

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get) question here tells me how to install a specific version i.e. x.y.

I would like to install a specific version of Python x.y.z - eg 3.6.3 - while the default in Ubuntu 18.04 is Python 3.6.8.

Is there a way to install the specific patch number of the version of Python?

I tried the selected answer in the related question and I cannot install properly.

```
sudo apt install python3.6.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.6.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6.3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6.3'
```

I am able to install a particular version, just not a patch number

```
sudo apt install python3.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib python3.5-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python3.5-venv python3.5-doc binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib python3.5 python3.5-minimal
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 501 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,113 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

```
sudo apt install python3.5.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.5.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.5.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.5.2'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/Python-3.5.0.tgz
tar xzvf Python-3.5.0.tgz
cd Python-3.5.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: So the only way is to install from source? Not from any ppa/repo?

Comment: I this the script above in Docker, and I got this error: `/bin/sh: 1: ./configure: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ./configure' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Comment: this also seems to require `build-essential` and `zlib1g-dev`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but instead of install from source yourself, you can use a tool like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to handle this. Example:

```
pyenv install 3.9.8
pyenv local 3.9.8  # Activate Python 3.9 for the current project or
pyenv global 3.9.8  # Activate Python 3.9 globaly
```

Read more about pyenv [here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/)