# Installing python3.5

Tags: python

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
I checked the following link:[installing python3.5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get)

I am trying to install python3.5.

```
$python --version
```

Python 2.7.15+
(envsp) @lc2530hz:~

When I used the command to add repository I got error messages:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

:
:

> Ign:36 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 18.04
>   InRelease         Err:37
>   http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 18.04 Release
>   404  Not Found [IP: 104.73.164.84 80] Reading package lists... Done E:
>   The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 18.04
>   Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a
>   repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
>   default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
>   configuration details. (envsp) zulfi@lc2530hz:~$

Somebody please guide me how to solve this problem.

Zulfi.

Comment: what do you need that version for?

Comment: Indeed. It comes with 3.6. You should try using 3.6, and if it indeed doesn't work for you, the easiest solution is to compile it from source.

Comment: `python3 --version` is the right command.

Comment: @Geroge I want to install Oyente tool: hhttps://medium.com/haloblock/how-to-use-oyente-a-smart-contract-security-analyzer-solidity-tutorial-86671be93c4b : $ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
But still not working for web3. I am starting another thread