# Ubuntu 20.04 gnome tweaks not working with python 3.9

Tags: python3, python-2.7, gnome-tweaks

I recently upgraded my default python version from 2.7 to 3.9.
I updated and upgraded, everything working fine except the gnome-tweak is not working or not apprearing.

Any kind of information would be appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 does not come with python2 installed, but only python 3.8.2 (which upgrades to 3.8.5) so the python 2.7 makes little sense.

Comment: Did you try to restart GNOME `Alt+F2 r`

Comment: You should not upgrade the default python. Instead read up on virtual python environments to use other versions of python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a different Python version using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get)