How to install python 3.12 on Linux
Trying to install a newer version of python in my system:
sudo apt-get install python3.12.7

E: Unable to locate package python3.12.7

How am I supposed to install a newer version of python. It locates python 3.8 ... but I need 3.12.

Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

This question is similar to: Installing python: who is deadsnakes and why should I trust them?. It describes how to install python3.9 manually. The same process will work for 3.12

Even if you install a new version of python, DO NOT make it the default. That will completely destroy your Ubuntu installation and you will have to reinstall. Instead, run it with the command python3.12

@ArchismanPanigrahi Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Does the answer in the link I posted solve your issue? Please let us know

Also: https://askubuntu.com/q/682869/124466

@ArchismanPanigrahi it worked. First I had to install 'software-properties-common', then add the ppa, then install python3.12
