# Ubuntu 14.04 Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.5.0-1 is installed

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, python

I have tried to install `python3.5` following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674586/python-3-5-has-just-been-released-can-i-get-it-as-a-package-for-ubuntu-15-4#answer-674600) instructions.

```
$ auto-apt run ./configure
$ make
# checkinstall
```

Actually `python3.5` works well. But during installation previous version was replaced.

```
# apt-get check 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-xapian-index : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.5.0-1 is installed
                    Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 cloud-image-utils : Depends: python:any
 compizconfig-settings-manager : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.5.0-1 is installed
                                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 duplicity : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.5.0-1 is installed
             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 euca2ools : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.5.0-1 is installed
             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 gconf2 : Depends: python:any
 gimp : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 hplip : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.5.0-1 is installed
 hplip-data : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ibus : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ibus-pinyin : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ...
```

And lot more.

```
# apt-get -f install
...
After this operation, 677 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?] _
```

I had similar issue when I have tried to remove python at all, I still didn't recover all removed packages, so:

Well, I have build and installed `python2.7.6` but now I have other issue

```
# apt-get upgrade | grep 'is installed'
 python-all : Depends: python (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but 2.7.6-1 is installed
 python-all-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but 2.7.6-1 is installed
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but 2.7.6-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded `*.deb` package for [`2.7.5-5ubuntu3`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/python/2.7.5-5ubuntu3) and installed using `dpkg` instead of `apt-get`

```
$ sudo dpkg --install python_2.7.5-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```